# What program to install to connect Visual Studio with a SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio

What program should I install to be able to connect Visual Studio 2017 with a SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)? I already installed "data storage and processing" workloads but I still got this error message:

[image]

Should I install SQL Server Management Studio? Or another program?

Comment: I would think that VS 2017 has all it needs to connect to your sql server. Are you sure the SQL Server is up and running, that the connectionstring you use is correct, that there are no firewall issues, etc...

Comment: Oh alright thanks, now i know that the error came out not because i didn't install the required program.